# Issue related to navigation dropdown

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a template and getting problem in adjusting the header. Everything is almost completed but header shows the problem. The problem is when one hover over the menu, it shows everything working great but one hover any nav item which have drop down menu, then it decreases the font size for the next item.

I have tried creating a new header also but still gets the same problem only when there is a drop down menu.

You can check the code at http://html.daatcreations.com/mobeva/

Comment: you can check it while hovering over Services, Blogs or pages in the header navbar.

Comment: Remember questions should be helpful to future readers. Please **include the code in the question itself** instead of linking to an external site that will change in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The artifact you are seeing isn't a change in the font size, it is caused by the rotateX transform. The browser is making room for the edge of the dropdown that has been rotated around the X-axis so you can see the edge.

It's hard to diagnose but it's easy to fix. You need to set the `backface-visibility` property to `hidden` on the elements that are rotating or making room for the rotated element's edge.

```
.dropdown {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```